# how to make string of brackets bracket is properly opened and closed in javascript

Tags: javascript

Please Someone should assist me. I need to write a function for a string of brackets. The string has any number of `(, ), [, ], {, and }`. A valid string follows the common-sense rules of opening and closing brackets, so in other words, the formal rules are:

There are an equal number of opening and closing brackets of each type. Each bracket is opened first, and later closed using the same type of bracket.

While a specific bracket is open, every other enclosed pair of brackets that is opened should be closed before the encompassing bracket closes.

For example, `{[()[]]()}()` is valid, but `[(])` is not.

Comment: Consider parsing the text into an AST and then looping through the nodes to see if the brackets are matching. Although this might be overkill...

Comment: You can use a stack, on open char, add to the top, on close char, pop the top item. At the end, if your stack is empty, everything is good

Comment: @thibsc much simpler!

Answer (score 1):

Each opened tag has to be closed, so you can do this by using a `stack`

```js
let correct = 'my st(ring) [ok] {hello}';
let uncorrect = 'my st(ring) [o(k] {hello}';

syntaxChecker = (str) => {
  let stack = [];
  // For each char in the string
  [...str].forEach(c => {
    // opened char ? add to the stack
    if ('([{'.includes(c)){
      stack.push(c);
    }
    // closed char ? check if match the last opened
    else if (')]}'.includes(c)){
      let top = stack.pop();
      if (! (c === ')' && top === '('
          || c === ']' && top === '['
          || c === '}' && top === '{')){
        stack.push(c);
      }
    }
  });
  // stack empty = correct
  return stack.length === 0;
}

console.log(syntaxChecker(correct)); // true
console.log(syntaxChecker(uncorrect)); // false
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the code doesn't work for all cases. `{{{{{{{{{{{{}}}}}}}}}}}}}` should produce true but it failed.

Comment: in which case it fails ? I updated my push in the closed condition, maybe it is better

Comment: @VictorUmeh the example input `{{{{{{{{{{{{}}}}}}}}}}}}}` is mismatched?

Comment: @VictorUmeh, you're sample is supposed to be false. You have 12 opened and 13 closed...

Comment: Okay, seen it. Thanks @thibsc for spotting the error.